# How to Create an Integer Column in a GXT Grid?

Tags: gxt

There have been a number of changes to the GXT library in version 3.1, and I'm not sure that I am using the correct technique for creating an editable integer column in a `Grid`. It seems that the required code is overly complex, but perhaps that's just how it is. Is there a better way than the following?

```java
ColumnConfig<M, Integer> column = new ColumnConfig<M, Integer>(valueProvider, width, title);
IntegerPropertyEditor editor = new NumberPropertyEditor.IntegerPropertyEditor();
NumberInputCell<Integer> cell = new NumberInputCell<>(editor);
new IntegerField(cell);
column.setCell(cell);
```

Note that if the `new IntegerField(cell)` statement is omitted then the column contains a numeric (integer) cell that contains a down arrow (like a combobox arrow), which seems odd.

Comment: Yes. Its correct approach. http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:inlineeditablegrid
The example shows, how to create editableGrid (but not using integer column)

Comment: @VivekVardhan But the example in my question is really not an example of the inline editable grid; it is closer to the cell grid, shown here: [Cell Grid](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:cellgrid). I originally started with the inline grid, but hoped that it would be simpler to avoid creation of the `GridInlineEditing` object and all the associated editors.